# How do you use wazuh with cert-manager in kubernetes?

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager, wazuh

The wazuh [kubernetes install instructions](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/deploying-with-kubernetes/kubernetes-conf.html) uses self signed certificates.

Is there a way to use cert-manager/LetsEncrypt certificates instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Kibana, you can easily use Trusted CA Signed SSL Certificates, for example Let's Encrypt, by placing them in `cert/kibana_http/`

```
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/<site-address>/privkey.pem certs/kibana_http/key.pem
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/<site-address>/fullchain.pem certs/kibana_http/cert.pem
```

For internal communications between the different Wazuh components, self-signed certificates are a good option given that they all verify the CA through a local file. Self-signed certificates also avoid the need for FQDN  which is required to get a certificate from a Trusted CA.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the self signed certs and they default to 10 years so renewal won't be an issue. Will look at using signed certs for kibana. Thanks!